# Even though the backbutton close is implemented, it does not work

Tags: android, flutter

Even though I implemented backbutton App close. If you press the backbutton, no message appears and you are returned to the login screen.

The homepage is running in the homescreen.
In order to find any possible errors, I put the backbutton close code in both places.

I am not sure what is wrong.

I need help.

#### HomeScreen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTime currentBackPressTime;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final FirebaseUser user;
  HomeScreen({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Navigation Drawer Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          bool result = onPressBackButton();
          return await Future.value(result);
        },
        child: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool onPressBackButton() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      scaffoldKey.currentState
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Tap back again to leave."),
        ));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}

  class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              primaryColor: Colors.white
          ),
          home: SideBarLayout(),
      );
    }
  }
```

#### HomeScreen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aciel_pro/navigation_bloc/navigation_bloc.dart';


class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTime currentBackPressTime;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Navigation Drawer Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          bool result = onPressBackButton();
          return await Future.value(result);
        },
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool onPressBackButton() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      scaffoldKey.currentState
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Tap back again to leave."),
        ));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}



class HomePage extends StatelessWidget with NavigationStates {
  BuildContext ctx;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ctx = context;

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('예약하기',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
              onPressed: () =>showMessage('예약하기'),
              color:Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        ),
        ),
    );
  }

  void showMessage(String msg) {
    final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(msg));

    Scaffold.of(ctx)
      ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1 : move  `final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();` out of `Home` 
Step 2 : add `Scaffold key`

```
return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
```

Step 3: `showMessage()` use `scaffoldKey`

```
scaffoldKey.currentState
  ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
  ..showSnackBar(snackbar);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTime currentBackPressTime;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Navigation Drawer Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          bool result = onPressBackButton();
          return await Future.value(result);
        },
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool onPressBackButton() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      scaffoldKey.currentState
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text("Tap back again to leave."),
        ));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  BuildContext ctx;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ctx = context;

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('예약하기', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
              onPressed: () => showMessage('예약하기'),
              color: Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showMessage(String msg) {
    final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(msg));

    scaffoldKey.currentState
      ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for useful information. But it keeps going over if something is wrong with the login page.

Probably everyone has a similar answer, so there's a problem inside, and in addition, the up and down global key crashes on both sides (backbutton, navigation). Will it be okay if I solve this?

Comment: In my example, all test is okay. Need to reproduce your question with more of your code.

Comment: ok very thank you :) 

I'll look for a little more and ask for help. Thank you for being so kind.